# dynamic_reconfigure: Why don't many ROS Navigation Plugins have add_dependencies() for gencfg in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile) to get dynamic_reconfigure to work on my own nav_stack plugin.

However, I notice that in ros navigation stack plugins, for example the global planners, in their[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/e7f13251b74fb9aa00200c675e655bfa376f5a14/global_planner/CMakeLists.txt), they do not declare

```
add_dependencies(plugin_name ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

Is there a reason why?

Thanks, Rico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361023/dynamic_reconfigure:-why-don%27t-many-ros-navigation-plugins-have-add_dependencies()-for-gencfg-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, I notice that in ros navigation stack plugins, for example the global planners, in their[CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/e7f13251b74fb9aa00200c675e655bfa376f5a14/global_planner/CMakeLists.txt), they do not declare
>
> ```
> add_dependencies(plugin_name ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
> ```
>
> Is there a reason why?

That target is included in `${planner_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`, so there is no need to list it separately.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-09-06**:
Nice! Can I ask is ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg target automatically included in ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}? If not, where is it included? Thanks,Rico

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-07**:
`${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}` does indeed contain the `_gencfg` target.

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-09-07**:
Awesome, Thanks!